# Is there a set of three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I claim the set of three linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$ to be empty.

But I'm not sure if the following proof is correct.

Let $x$ and $y$ be linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{C}^2$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$.
Assume that $z \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ is not a linear combination of $x$ and $y$.
Then, for all $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ in $\mathbb{C}$, we have that

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
z & = & z_1 (1, 0) + z_2 (0, 1) \\
& \neq & \alpha_1 x + \alpha_2 y \\
& = & (\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 y_1)(1, 0) + (\alpha_1 x_2 + \alpha_2 x_2)(0, 1).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

This requires that either $z_1 \neq (\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2y_1)$, or $z_2 \neq (\alpha_1x_2 + \alpha_2y_2)$, or both.

But if $z_1 \neq (\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2y_1)$, for all $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$, this can only be the case if $x_1 = y_1 = 0$. This, in turn, causes $\{x, y\}$ to be linearly dependent, contradicting the assumption. A similar argument applies for $z_2$. Hence, either $z = 0$ or $z$ is a linear combination of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Your notation is confusing. You start  with $x,y$ linearly independent, but then mix it with $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$?

Comment: You didn't really prove the statement of last paragraph after "But if".

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^2$ has $\text{dim}$ $4$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R},$ but $\text{dim}$ $2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: Thank you for your help @DietrichBurde! My understanding is that for any vector $x$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$, we have that $x = x_1(1, 0) + x_2(0, 1)$.

Comment: What is your scalar field? $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$? You should be explicit and say, since it affects the answer.

Comment: @MaxHerrmann The phrase" Then, for all $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$" is not true. Take $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$ and $z=0$.